# How to use a circleType for several elements

Tags: html, css

I want all labels to have a circleType. When I define a circleType only for one label with getElementById , it succeeds. But when I use getElementsByClassName it does not work.

```
<div id="playlistAll">
    <div class="divHover">
        <label class="class-name" id="first">AAAAA</label>
        <div class="playlistCon">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="divHover">
        <label class="class-name">BBBBBB</label>
        <div class="playlistCon">
        </div>
    </div>
```

working

```
const circleType = new CircleType(document.getElementById('first'));
 circleType.radius(100);
```

not working

```
const circleType = new CircleType(document.getElementsByClassName('class-name'));
 circleType.radius(100);
```

Does anyone have an idea?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [readme](https://github.com/peterhry/CircleType/blob/master/README.md) for CircleType indicates that the constructor only accepts an HTML element, not elements. So, if you really want to use that class for multiple elements, you'll probably need to loop over each element and create an instance of CircleType for each one.

Comment: I create the labels dynamically. In what other way can I set the label to be rounded to everyone?

Comment: You could always tinker with the CSS border-radius property.

Comment: Border-radius makes the label border rounded but not the text, am I wrong?

Comment: Correct. It only affects the border of the label.

Comment: Is there a way to affects the text of some labels?

Comment: There's always a way, but I'm not quite sure what to recommend. As I  suggested in my answer, you can always use document.getElementsByClassName('class-name'), like you were, and loop through the results of that, creating a new instance of CircleType for each label.

Comment: Thank you very much - I succeeded with your help. I am new to the programming world and I hope that in the future my understanding of this fascinating world will improve.

Answer (score 0):

```
var circles = document.getElementsByClassName("circulate");

for (var i = 0; i < circles.length; i++) {
    var circleType = new CircleType(circles.item(i));
}
```